# ADB Shell doesn’t install apks

Tags: android, apk, adb, root, auto

It works for both front monitors, with adb install -g [path], but it doesn’t work for third one

Also, adb install [path] only installs application on first of three monitors

My car is LiXian L7, does anybody know how can i make it?

Comment: Be more specific. Don't know what _monitors_ you are talking about.

Comment: monitors for watching, idk how to say
like this https://i.cbc.ca/1.4972585.1547086762!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_780/tech-ces-screens.jpg

Comment: And each monitor has it's own Android system? because usually APK files are simply installed to the OS so it doesn't matter how many monitors you have. BTW: Please edit your question and describe in detail your environment, what you are trying to do and what goes wrong, because the number of people here on SO who are familiar with Android in LiXian L7 is very very low.

Comment: Is it one system with multiple displays or multiple android systems interconnected?

Comment: i think it's multiple android systems interconnected, coz now i can watch 2 different films on both front monitors